# Display text if value is plural using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Hi guys i got this ampscript with help from this community.
I want to be able to add a text depending if the output is plural or not.

```
%%[
set @phone_number_list = "1111111;1111111;1111111;2222222;1111111;3333333"

/* initialize empty collection */
set @phone_number_collection = "" 

set @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@phone_number_list, ";")

for @i = 1 to RowCount(@rows) do
  set @row = Row(@rows, @i)
  set @phone_number = Field(@row, 1)

  /* wrapped in arbitrary delimiters to ensure unique string */
  set @phone_number_item = Concat("~", @phone_number, "~")

  /* only output if phone number doesn't exist in collection */
  if IndexOf(@phone_number_collection, @phone_number_item) < 1 then
]%%

%%=V(@phone_number)=%%<br>

%%[
  endif

  /* add phone number to collection */
  set @phone_number_collection = Concat(
    @phone_number_collection,
    @phone_number_item
  )

next @i
]%%
```

> Output
>   
> 1111111
>   
> 2222222
>   3333333

I would like to add some text. If output contain more than one unique phone number, I would like to add: "Your phone numbers" (Plural) and if output only contain one phone number add "Your phone number".

**Desired output If output contains more than one phone number:**

> Output:
>   
> 1111111
>   
> 2222222
>
> Your phone numbers 1111111, 2222222

**Desired output If output contains one phone number:**

> Output:
>   
> 1111111
>   Your phone number 1111111

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
%%[

set @list = "1111111;1111111;1111111;2222222;1111111;3333333"
set @collection = "" 
set @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@list, ";")
set @unique = 0

for @i = 1 to RowCount(@rows) do

  set @row = Row(@rows, @i)
  set @phone_number = Field(@row, 1)

  if @i < rowcount(@rows) then 
    set @phone_number_item = Concat(@phone_number, ", ")
  else
    set @phone_number_item = Concat(@phone_number)
  endif

  if IndexOf(@collection, @phone_number_item) < 1 then
     set @collection = Concat(@collection, @phone_number_item)
  endif

next @i

if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromString(@collection, ", ")) > 1 then
  output(concat("Your phone numbers: ", @collection))
else
  output(concat("Your phone number: ", @collection))
endif

]%%
```

**Output**:

> Your phone numbers: 1111111, 2222222, 3333333

With a single number:

```
%%[

set @list = "1111111"
set @collection = "" 
set @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@list, ";")
set @unique = 0

for @i = 1 to RowCount(@rows) do

  set @row = Row(@rows, @i)
  set @phone_number = Field(@row, 1)

  if @i < rowcount(@rows) then 
    set @phone_number_item = Concat(@phone_number, ", ")
  else
    set @phone_number_item = Concat(@phone_number)
  endif

  if IndexOf(@collection, @phone_number_item) < 1 then
    set @collection = Concat(@collection, @phone_number_item)
  endif

next @i

if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromString(@collection, ", ")) > 1 then
  output(concat("Your phone numbers: ", @collection))
else
  output(concat("Your phone number: ", @collection))
endif

]%%
```

**Output**:

> Your phone number: 1111111

Updated to handle a single duplicated number:

```
%%[

set @list = "1111111;1111111"
set @collection = "" 
set @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@list, ";")
set @rowCount =  RowCount(@rows)

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

  set @row = Row(@rows, @i)
  set @phone_number = Field(@row, 1)

  if indexOf(@collection, @phone_number) == 0 then

    if @i == @rowCount then 
      set @collection = concat(@collection, @phone_number)
    else
      set @collection = concat(@collection, @phone_number, ", ")
    endif

  endif

next @i

if substring(@collection,subtract(length(@collection),1),2) == ", " then
   set @collection = substring(@collection,1,subtract(length(@collection),2))
endif

if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromString(@collection, ", ")) > 1 then
  output(concat("<br>Your phone numbers: ", @collection))
else
  output(concat("<br>Your phone number: ", @collection))
endif

]%%
```

**Output**:

> Your phone number: 1111111

Comment: Fast one Adam ;)

Comment: `set @phone_number_list = "1111111, 1111111"` or `set @phone_number_list = "1111111, 1111111"` big difference, comma or semicolon? With comma it does not work because the seperator is a semicolon ;

Comment: Hi Adam! Thank you very much for this. However I have found an error that i have tried to fix edititing you ampscript, but I can't make it work. If I set @phone_number_list = "1111111;1111111" The output is: Your phone numbers 1111111

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you Adam! This is great. It is very appreciated. I must be honest. I am a bit starstruck by you. Have read some many question where you have solved the question.

Answer (score 0):

I will edit this code with comments later on ;)
But since Adam already answered with a ampscript-block only code, i would take his one. I just edited your code which was not ideal, Adam edited it to the next level. But both of them deliver the expected result (i believe).

```
%%[
set @phone_number_list = "1111111;1111111;1111111;2222222;1111111;3333333"

/* initialize empty collection */
set @phone_number_collection = "" 

set @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@phone_number_list, ";")

set @row_count = RowCount(@rows)
if @row_count == 1 then
  set @row = Row(@rows, 1)
  set @phone_number = Field(@row, 1)
]%%

%%=Concat("Your phone number ",@phone_number)=%%<br>

%%[
else
for @i = 1 to @row_count do
  set @row = Row(@rows, @i)
  set @phone_number = Field(@row, 1)

  /* wrapped in arbitrary delimiters to ensure unique string, i Dont get this therefore deleted the Concat~ */
  set @phone_number_item = @phone_number

  /* only output if phone number doesn't exist in collection */
  if IndexOf(@phone_number_collection, @phone_number_item) < 1 then
    /* add phone number to collection */
    if @i == 1 then 
       set @phone_number_collection = @phone_number_item
    else
    set @phone_number_collection = Concat(@phone_number_collection," , ",@phone_number_item)
    endif
  endif
next @i
]%%
%%=Concat("Your phone numbers ",@phone_number_collection)=%%<br>
%%[
endif
]%%
```

My second approach for your Duplicate but same number problem would have been (taking adams first code):

```
%%[

set @phone_number_list = "1111111;1111111;1111111;1111111;1111111"
set @phone_number_collection = "" 
set @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@phone_number_list, ";")
set @counter = 0

for @i = 1 to RowCount(@rows) do

  set @row = Row(@rows, @i)
  set @phone_number = Field(@row, 1)

  if @i < rowcount(@rows) then 
    set @phone_number_item = Concat(@phone_number, ", ")
  else
    set @phone_number_item = Concat(@phone_number)
  endif

  if IndexOf(@phone_number_collection, @phone_number_item) < 1 then
    set @phone_number_collection = Concat(@phone_number_collection, @phone_number_item)
    set @counter = Add(@counter,1)
  endif

next @i

if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromString(@phone_number_collection, ", ")) > 1 and @counter > 1 then
  output(concat("Your phone numbers: ", @phone_number_collection))
else
  output(concat("Your phone number: ", @phone_number))
endif

]%%
```

Comment: Hi Johannes - Thank you for the comments. It is very useful for a beginner as me. As i have written to Adam, there is flaw when the set @phone_number_list = "1111111, 1111111" The output is: Your phone numbers 1111111

Comment: `set @phone_number_list = "1111111, 1111111"` or `set @phone_number_list = "1111111, 1111111"` big difference, comma or semicolon? With comma it does not work because the seperator is a semicolon ;

Comment: Sorry, it is semicolon. It works fine with semicolon, but the output will only show one number, but the text is the plural text "Your phone numbers"

Comment: updated my answer with a different method for a duplicate of the same number

Comment: Thank you Johannes! It worked. Vielen Dank! I will now try to understand the code, so I can do it myself in the future :)